# How to keep track of which posts have been liked by a user?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am working on an application that allows users to like content, which will be visualized by changing an outlined heart icon to a fully filled heart icon if the user has liked that post.

I have a list-page that renders every post in the database as a `Content Card` component. That component contains the icon mentioned above. In order to decide whether the component should be rendered with the outlined or the filled heart, I need a way of establishing whether the user has liked the corresponding post or not.

**What I currently do**

Every like is it's own model instance of `Like` which has a Foreign key pointing to the post that is associated with it. I have an API endpoint at `content/likes/?post_id=${postID}` which gives me all of the users that have liked the given post.

For every post on the page, I call this endpoint and then loop over the response to see if the logged in user is in that list of users who liked the content. If that's the case, I set a piece of state to true and the heart is filled for that post.

My approach works fine **but** I am making a separate request for every post on the page. Let's say I have 100 posts displaying, I assume that it wouldn't be a best practice to make 100 requests just to fill that icon.

I have been thinking about ways to improve this but I am not sure how people usually handle this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

How about a batch likes endpoint?

```
content/batch_likes/?post_ids=1,2,3,4,5...
```

and a return value of either liked IDs

```
[1,3,5]
```

or a map of liked-ness:

```
{"1": true, "2": false, "3": true, "4": false, "5": true}
```

These can both be implemented very efficiently:
List:

```
liked_ids = Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, post_id__in=post_ids).values_list('post_id', flat=True)
```

Dict (using the above):

```
like_map = dict.fromkeys(post_id, False)
like_map.update({liked_id: True for liked_id in liked_ids})
```

---

EDIT:

You can also expose this in a DRF serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_liked = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    # ... other fields and meta ...

    def get_user_liked(self, obj) -> bool:
        # See if we'd cached this...
        if hasattr(obj, '_user_liked'):
             return obj._user_liked
        # Or if we didn't, do a query (boo-hoo, slow)
        return self.obj.like_set.filter(user=self.context['request'].user).exists()
```

You can then add a Prefetch in your DRF viewset to get that `_user_liked` "cache" property for your objects in a single query.

Another mechanism for doing the user like cache might be to stow a map in that serializer context.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a shot. However, I am wondering if it would be possible to send the information about whether the user liked the post together with the rest of the posts contents?

Comment: @PhilippK Sure is. Added that in, too.

Comment: Thanks, that looks really promising! Not sure about how I would go about prefetching - a quick search tells me that I would do something like `queryset.prefetch_related('_user_liked')` or am I going in the wrong direction with this?

Comment: Come to think of it, you should be able to do it with `annotate(_user_liked=Count("like_set", filter=Q(user=self.request.user))` or similar...

Comment: Thanks for your help but I keep running into errors unfortunately